# How can you apply a custom function to a column in pandas dataframe and store the output in a column of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to call a specific function passing it each row of a particular column in a dataframe (df) and then store the return of that function in another dataframe (df3).

This is the function:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import re                             #enables carrier lookup

    def recognize_delivery_service(tracking):
    service = None

usps_pattern = [
    '^(94|93|92|94|95)[0-9]{20}$',
    '^(94|93|92|94|95)[0-9]{22}$',
    '^(70|14|23|03)[0-9]{14}$',
    '^(M0|82)[0-9]{8}$',
    '^([A-Z]{2})[0-9]{9}([A-Z]{2})$'
]

ups_pattern = [
    '^(1Z)[0-9A-Z]{16}$',
    '^(T)+[0-9A-Z]{10}$',
    '^[0-9]{9}$',
    '^[0-9]{26}$'
]

fedex_pattern = [
    '^[0-9]{20}$',
    '^[0-9]{15}$',
    '^[0-9]{12}$',
    '^[0-9]{22}$'
]

usps = "(" + ")|(".join(usps_pattern) + ")"
fedex = "(" + ")|(".join(fedex_pattern) + ")"
ups= "(" + ")|(".join(ups_pattern) + ")"

if re.match(usps, tracking) != None:
    service = 'USPS'
elif re.match(ups, tracking) != None:
    service = 'UPS'
elif re.match(fedex, tracking) != None:
    service = 'FedEx'

return service

    #Pass tracking to function

    temp_track = None
    temp_service = None

    for i in range(len(df)):
        temp_track = df.iloc[i, 44]                           #tracking num located in column 44
    temp_service = recognize_delivery_service(temp_track) #pass track num to function
    df3.iloc[i, 0] = temp_service                         #store service value in column 0 of df3
```

This is one of many attempts I've made but can't get the function to return proper service nor store in df3.

Comment: I got it to work by adding a column to df to store the value in the iteration look and then assigned df to df3 after the loop was complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understood what this function should do, but I think `pandas.apply` might be relevant...
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

if you could give an example of input and desired output I could help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I put in the comment above that I got it to work.

for i in range(len(df)):
    temp_track = df.iloc[i, 57]     #tracking num located in column 44
    temp_service = recognize_delivery_service(temp_track) #pass track num to function
    df.iloc[i, 57] = temp_service